# SonarLint not working properly with sonarQube 6.5

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonarlint

SonarLint is not working properly in online mode. The maven project is well binded to the SonarQube project, but when analysing the analyse can't find out issues that are already detected by SonarQube server. After sonarLint analyse with 0 found issues. It try to read issues from server and I get the following excetpion :

```
java.lang.IllegalSt  ateException: Fail to request http://nx-analysis:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=com.sungard.decalog.framework%3Acommon-util
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.util.ws.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:179)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.util.ws.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:111)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.util.ws.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:100)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.SonarLintWsClient.rawGet(SonarLintWsClient.java:112)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.SonarLintWsClient.get(SonarLintWsClient.java:77)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.upd  ate.ModuleQualityProfilesDownloader.fetchModuleQualityProfiles(ModuleQualityProfilesDownloader.java:45)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.upd  ate.ModuleConfigur  ationDownloader.fetchProjectQualityProfiles(ModuleConfigur  ationDownloader.java:58)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.upd  ate.ModuleConfigur  ationDownloader.fetchModuleConfigur  ation(ModuleConfigur  ationDownloader.java:43)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.upd  ate.perform.ModuleStorageUpd  ateExecutor.upd  ateModuleConfigur  ation(ModuleStorageUpd  ateExecutor.java:71)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.upd  ate.perform.ModuleStorageUpd  ateExecutor.lambda$upd  ate$0(ModuleStorageUpd  ateExecutor.java:64)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.client.api.util.FileUtils.replaceDir(FileUtils.java:150)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.upd  ate.perform.ModuleStorageUpd  ateExecutor.upd  ate(ModuleStorageUpd  ateExecutor.java:63)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.ConnectedContainer.upd  ateModule(ConnectedContainer.java:117)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.upd  ateModule(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:260)
  at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.server.Server.upd  ateProjectStorage(Server.java:338)
  at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ProjectUpd  ateJob.run(ProjectUpd  ateJob.java:49)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) 
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(N  ative Method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
  at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
  at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:236)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:344)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:216)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:210)
  at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.util.ws.OkHttpClientBuilder.setUserAgent(OkHttpClientBuilder.java:193)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
  at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
  at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
  at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.util.ws.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:176)
... 16 more
```

Comment: Can you manually check with a web browser if the URL in the first line of the error message is correct?

Comment: With a web browser I can download a file named "issues" containing the issues in the server.

Comment: Is `nx-analysis` a server in your local network? Could you [try to replace in the server URL `nx-analysis` with the IP address or the full domain name](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/A1u5pKi85LA)?